# Boton que ejecute un script que llame a un archivo php sin que recargue la pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<"span class="a-button a-button-span12 a-button-primary"><"span class="a- 
  button-inner"><"input id="signInSubmit" tabindex="5" class="a-button- 
  input" type="submit"><"span id="auth-signin-button-announce" class="a- 
  button-text" aria-hidden="true"> <!-- boton de ejecutar -->
            Sign-In
<"/span><"/span><"/span>
```

Necesito que ese botón ejecute un script que haga ejecutar un archivo php y que no se recargue la página

el archivo hace que lo que esta en el formulario se envie a un documento html. que ese ya lo tengo el script en php ya lo tengo pero cuando le doy al boton me manda a la pagina del script y lo que quiero es que se quede en la misma página del formulario.

Comment: Onion test, lo que te puedo decir es que ese es el típico comportamiento que habitualmente se espera al ejecutar un archivo php, la única forma de ejecutarlo sería yendo a su dirección... Si no vas a ese archivo no se va ejecutar. Ahora también decirte que php es un lenguaje del lado del servidor, así que no podrás hacerlo de la forma que pretendes. Pero Carlos Alberto Marrufo te dio una muy buena opción para solucionar tu problema, te sugiero que lo apliques.

Answer (score 2):

onion test, para ello recomiendo trabajar con 3 archivos, el archivo en donde haces la interfaz, el archivo donde realizas los scripts y el archivo php para las consultas.
El archivo de tu interfaz ya lo tenemos, sólo falta que enlaces el archivo JavaScript añadiendo `<script src="TuArchivo.js"></script>` al `head` del primer archivo mencionado.

Bien, ahora utilizaremos el archivo JavaScript como intermedio entre el `html` y el `.php`, por lo que tu botón quedaría así:

```
<form id = "miFormulario">
<"input id="signInSubmit" tabindex="5" class="a-button-input" type="submit">
</form>
```

Ahora en el archivo de JavaScript añadiríamos la función:

```
$('#miFormulario').submit(function (e) {
    //La función a realizar, en este caso, llamar al archivo de PHP.
    e.preventDefault(); //añado esta línea para evitar que el submit recargue la página y se borren los datos
})
```

Existen varios metodos para realizar la conexión con el archivo PHP, `$.ajax`, `$.post`, `$.get`, entre otros...

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenido a *StackOverflow* **onion test**, efectivamente las recomendacion de **Víctor Hugo Tirado** y la respuesta de **Carlos Alberto Marrufo** son acertadas, personalemente una respuesta de mi parte mas especifica a tu caso seria la siguiente:

```js
window.onload = function() {

    var botonSingIn = document.getElementById('signInSubmit');
    
    botonSingIn.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    
        // instanciamos el objeto XMLHttpRequest para 
        // realizar una peticion sin recargar la pagina.
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            // evaluamos las respuestas del servidor para
            // asegurarnos de que todo a salido bien.
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                // this.responseText contiene la salida
                // despues de procesar el archivo.php
                document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "archivo.php", true);
        // si usamos POST debemos colocar la siguiente linea...
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("variable1=foo&variable2=bar"); // aqui enviamos los datos

    });

}
```

```html
<span class="a-button a-button-span12 a-button-primary">
    <span class="a-button-inner">
        <input id="signInSubmit" tabindex="5" class="a-button-input" type="submit">
        <span id="auth-signin-button-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">
            Sign-In
        </span>
    </span>
</span>

<div id="resultado">
    <!-- Aqui se insertara el resultado de forma asincrona -->
</div>
```